# Accessing properties of window with Selenium

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium

The page I am trying to test sets the value of "global variables". From the Firebug, I can access those as properties of the window object (e.g. window.foo).

From Selenium however, typeof selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().foo always return "undefined", say when used in the condition of a waitForCondition. Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it cant be done, it could be done in greasemonkey using unsafeWindow, however that doesnt work in selenium. i tried to do it using

```
addLocationStrategy
zzz
return prompt(inWindow.a);
```

and than

```
click
zzz=xxx
```

but i cant access it. if you have any ideas how to do it let me know.

if its your page maybe you could keep that variable in some html control. its a hack, but .....

Comment: So you are saying that when I want to check something (assertion), I can only check things on the DOM, not attributes of the window object?

Comment: it sure looks like some people are successfully doing this: http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/?p=111 (`js_condition = “selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0”;

$selenium.wait_for_condition(js_condition, timeout)`. I've got the same problem though!